Tomcat startup issue (error contains db2 and timer details)
Good morning, we have been running the server for a few weeks now without much issues but randomly while starting tomcat it throws an error, having a hard time to solve and currently stuck not being able to run the server. This is the contents of the error:
20-Sep-2024 13:51:51.584 INFO [Timer-0] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [com/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2JccConfiguration.properties]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [com/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2JccConfiguration.properties]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1384)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1034)
                at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.vd.run(vd.java:70)
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.GlobalProperties.a(GlobalProperties.java:152)
                at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.GlobalProperties.d(GlobalProperties.java:100)
                at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ar.run(ar.java:124)
                at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
                at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

Currently I am trying to download the DB2 installer from IBM after waiting for their approval to show the link (registering credentials on IBM was buggy).I am not sure if the installation will solve the problem as it might be that the DB2 drivers aren't properly installed yet, or there might be a versioning problem in the current software line-up (apache, db2, java, one or all of them).Thanks for any help.
ps. sometimes the error goes away by itself by restarting the server several times or after a few days. I thought it was a threading problem or improper shutting down of the server that led to some process residue still running.

Is Timer.java a file of yours?

This is not a programming question, instead it is about troubleshooting. Please edit your question to add missing facts, the exact operating-system details, the version of the jvm/jdk in use, the exact version of the Db2 driver and its type, details of whether you altered the DB2JccConfiguration.properties file and how etc.

"...Could not load [com/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2JccConfiguration.properties]..." -- This file does not exist in the current version (11.5) of the JDBC driver. Why is it looking for? What version of the JCC driver do you have? Anyway, I would upgrade to 11.5.9.0 available in Maven Central.

OS: windows (think it's 10 or 11), java jdk 11/13, jcc driver - it currently has a jcc .jar inside the apache lib folder but it doesn't specify what version it is, how can you check?, sorry this is the computer of my teammate at work I can't see it at the moment he's busy with tasks, I'm helping him.. by the way, is the versioning really important? I just downloaded the db2 jar from the previous comment.. do I just put it in the lib folder? IBM's site is confusing to navigate, took a while to find files, I dl'd the 1.3 db2 installer and a few driver fix/update links. still unsure.
